# Group by a distinct list of integers

Tags: c#, linq

```
MyObject()
{
     String dept;
     List<int> id;
     Object obj;
}
```

Using `LINQ`, how can I return a list of the above objects organized as follows:

Group all of the obj objects by [ department and EQUAL id list ].  The list being considered equal if it contains the same numbers, not necessarily the same order(a set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GroupBy` has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334.aspx) that accepts a custom `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>`. Write one that regards two objects as equal when `dept` is equal and `id` is set-equal, and pass it as an argument.

A convenient way to implement set equality is to write

```
new HashSet(x.id).SetEquals(new HashSet(y.id))
```

although this will end up being inefficient and probably not the best idea if there are lots of comparisons to make.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12708285/480799), if efficiency is an issue, you can store the `HashSet` for each object in an anonymous object:

```
myObjects.Select(x => new { myObject = x, hashSet = new HashSet(x.id) })
         .GroupBy(x => x.hashSet, HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer())
         .SelectMany(x => x.GroupBy(y => y.myObject.dept))
```

If you want to perform only one `GroupBy` you could store the `HashSet` in a `Tuple` or custom class, but then you would have to create your own `IEqualityComparer`.